# Pretty print JavaScript code in Visual Studio 2012 while debugging

Tags: javascript, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013

I'm an ASP.NET developer and I haven't tried debugging JavaScript in a while and thought I'd try it out again.  In general, it's a pretty nice experience, it's nice having the "go to definition" like in C#.

However, I'm trying to figure out where a variable is getting set in my call stack.  I go up a couple levels in my call stack and I get to a big ugly chunk of minified JavaScript.  I don't see anyway to pretty print this like I can do with the IE Developer tools so I can figure out where I am.

Is there anyway to do this in Visual Studio 2013?

Thanks,
Eric

Comment: It's in a different solution.  All of the JavaScript that I'm debugging is in a different solution than the ASP.NET website that I'm debugging.  It doesn't sound like I can really do this in Visual Studio.